# I want to use a iTunes voucher but not sure if it will charge my dad's credit card

Tags: itunes

I tried use iTunes voucher but I am not sure if it will charge my dad. How do I know?

Answer (score 1):

Voucher Cards can't be used to submit Money back to a Credit Card the equivalent Amount of Money is just added to the iTunes Accounts Balance.

As long as you have your own iTunes Account you're in the clear and your Dad can't access your Money.

Comment: t̫h̫x̫ b̫u̫t̫ w̫i̫l̫l̫ h̫e̫ g̫e̫t̫ a̫ e̫m̫a̫i̫l̫ w̫h̫e̫n̫ i̫ b̫u̫y̫ s̫o̫m̫e̫t̫h̫i̫n̫g̫ u̫s̫i̫n̫g̫ v̫o̫u̫c̫h̫e̫r̫

Comment: if the email address used to sign in to itunes account is his then yes if its your own account with your on email address then you get the notification

Comment: o̫h̫ s̫o̫ h̫e̫ w̫o̫u̫l̫d̫ n̫o̫ k̫n̫o̫w̫ i̫f̫ i̫ b̫o̫u̫g̫h̫t̫ s̫o̫m̫e̫t̫h̫i̫n̫g̫

Comment: yes - but what will you buy what your dad should not know?

Comment: Nothing just I would have to pay him even though I already paid for it on my ipad

Answer (score 0):

1. As long as the app's price does not exceed the amount of money on your iTunes Balance, and you actually pay with the gift card.
2. If the Apple ID belongs to you, you will get the notification. If it belongs to your father, however, then he will get it. It all depends on who owns the e-mail address associated with the Apple ID you are trying to use.